# Navigating to Lat/Long in QGIS with a relative coordinate system

Tags: qgis, navigation

It seems really fundamental, but how do I pan the map center to a decimal lat/long in QGIS? I would type in the lat/long at the bottom, but I use WGS 84/Pseudo Mercator to use the streetmap from openlayers which shows the x/y distance instead of absolute coordinates. If I change the projection, the streetmap gets unaligned even with OTF CRS transformation enabled.

I do not want to search for the coordinate with my mouse (i.e. using coordinate capture), I just need to pan the center of the map.
It's easy to do in google earth (just search for the lat/long), ArcMap (Go to XY in the toolbar) and MapInfo (Map->Change View). I can even geocode addresses (geosearch plugin) in QGIS easier.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the **Zoom to Point** plugin which allows you to enter the coordinates for either geographic or projected data:

[image: Zoom to Point plugin]

You can obtain this from the toolbar:

*Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins*